# Build failure after running pod update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I ran `pod update` and two libraries were updated. I then opened xcode and tried to build and run the application but the libraries that were updated both failed to build, one gave 65 compile errors and the other gave 27.

I have tried

- Updaing cocoapods to the latest version but it made no difference
- `pod cache clean --all`, also no difference
- Confirmed `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` is set the same in the pods and my app (both set to yet)
- Reverting to the pervious versions of the libraries, still have compile errors despite them being in use for months before this without a problem

The libraries not compiling are SwiftyJSON and Kingfisher.

Here is a sample of the errors being produced, the selected error in the left pane is the top error in the right pane.
[image: Here is a sample of the errors being produced, the selected error in the left pane is the top error in the right pane]

What other issues could be causing this problem?

Edit: The pod file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Starscream', '~> 0.9.3'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 1.5'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Comment: What's written in your Podfile

Comment: I've added it to the post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I dont actually have a solution as to what was causing this but updating to Xcode 7 fixed it.